# how to address zip list in sort lambda

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a class with 2 attributes which are lists themselves:

```
class data...:
    list1 = [["g1", 2.0], ["x1", 3.0]...] # n elements
    list2 = [[2, 4, 5],[3, 2, 1]...] # n elements
```

I need to zip sort both lists, based on value of the second element of `list2`.

```
zipped = zip(dataobj.list1, dataobj.list2)
zipped.sort(cmp = lambda k: dataobj.list2[2])
```

This seems to not work.

How do I reference the second element of `dataobj.list2[2]` as this is not working and gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: `zipped.sort(key = lambda k: k[1][1])`?

Comment: zipped.sort(key = lambda k: k[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp` should be a reference to a function that compares two values. Instead, you need something much simpler - a `key` field.

The easiest way would be to reference the value directly from `zipped` instead of going back to the original value in `list2`. Note, BTW, that lists in python are zero-based, so the second element would be `[1]`, not `[2]`. To make a long story short:

```
zipped.sort(key = lambda k : k[1][1])
```